# how to detect keypress/keydown for special characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, keycode, onkeydown

I need to trigger a javascript event on keypress. so when a use types ')' it triggers an event. 
I'm unable to find out keyCode for this. 
Any help please?

Comment: Try these https://keycode.info/

Comment: this should help https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Comment: https://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html

Comment: Just press the keys you want to find the codes/identifiers for in here: https://keyjs.dev

Answer (score 2):

The 0 and ) share the same keycode (48). Instead of using keycode you can use event.key to get the actual key being pressed during the event.

Here is a good resource for figuring out keys and keycodes:
https://keycode.info/

And to get the event you need to bind a keydown function to the element using that elements ID:

```
$( "#target" ).keydown(function(event) {
  if(event.key === ")") {
    //Do something...
  }
});
```

Comment: This should have been marked as the accepted answer.  Anyway, check this out, it's a similar tool but with a few additional features: https://keyjs.dev 

Answer (score 1):

Try using the mentioned link
https://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html

You can get access to the strokes using which in event listener if you want to use

Thanks

Comment: An alternative tool with a few additional features a nicer UI: https://keyjs.dev  Also, if you need more details about the events than those on the screen, just open DevTools and you will have everything you need there! 